# How to change radio button place & add line separator

Tags: javascript, html, css, sapui5

I've tried to change the layout of the following without success,
what I need is that the dropdownbox will be in parallel to the second (RB2)radio button (on the right side) and not below.
http://jsbin.com/xijohaqaci/1/edit?js,output

In addition I need to add line separator(thin line) between below the title and before the radio buttons,how it can achieved?

for those who wonder what it is ,this is SAPUI5

https://github.com/SAP/openui5/

In the **renderer** you should put the Html/Css(any native...) which is describe how the controls will look like. e.g. for the control to be vertical i've added

```
oRm.writeAttribute('style','display:flex;flex-direction:column;align-items:flex-start');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you could wrap the `_radioButtonGroup` and `_dropDownBox` in a `<div>`, then apply a `margin-top` to align the dropdown with the second radio button:

JS:

```
renderer: function(oRm, oControl) {
    oRm.write("<div");
    oRm.writeAttribute('style','display:flex;flex-direction:column;align-items:flex-start;');
    oRm.writeControlData(oControl);
    oRm.writeClasses();
    oRm.write(">");
    oRm.renderControl(oControl._title);
    oRm.write("<hr");
    oRm.writeAttribute('style','border:0;display:block;width:100%;background-color:black;height:1px;');
    oRm.write(">");
    oRm.write("<div>");
    oRm.renderControl(oControl._radioButtonGroup);
    oRm.renderControl(oControl._dropDownBox);
    oRm.write("</div>");
    oRm.write("</div>");
  }
```

CSS:

```
#__box0 {
  margin-top: 22px;
}
```

Then you can add an `<hr>` with the appropriate styles to get a horizontal line.

[See it on JSBin here.](http://jsbin.com/fawamatuku/1/edit?js,output)